# How to resolve this issue "Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl"?

Tags: android, android-studio

Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AidlCompile$AidlCompileRunnable
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\Awara\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.3\aidl.exe with arguments {-pC:\Users\Awara\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-30\framework.aidl -oE:\Android Studio\Compressed\Games\dashlane-6feb21\codecanyon-30280514-dashlane-android-studio-facebook-ads-ready-to-publish\dashlane-codecanyon-fb\android_code\dashlane-facebook-ads-1.0.0\android\app\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\out -IE:\Android Studio\Compressed\Games\dashlane-6feb21\codecanyon-30280514-dashlane-android-studio-facebook-ads-ready-to-publish\dashlane-codecanyon-fb\android_code\dashlane-facebook-ads-1.0.0\android\app\src\main\aidl -IE:\Android Studio\Compressed\Games\dashlane-6feb21\codecanyon-30280514-dashlane-android-studio-facebook-ads-ready-to-publish\dashlane-codecanyon-fb\android_code\dashlane-facebook-ads-1.0.0\android\app\src\debug\aidl -IC:\Users\Awara.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4295e8b6083028f8915ba1aa4957e660\transformed\core-1.0.0\aidl -IC:\Users\Awara.gradle\caches\transforms-3\7484187bc104e695a3061702a24e4a46\transformed\versionedparcelable-1.0.0\aidl -dC:\Users\Awara\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl16073758021056375721.d E:\Android Studio\Compressed\Games\dashlane-6feb21\codecanyon-30280514-dashlane-android-studio-facebook-ads-ready-to-publish\dashlane-codecanyon-fb\android_code\dashlane-facebook-ads-1.0.0\android\app\src\main\aidl\com\android\vending\billing\IInAppBillingService.aidl}

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Please provide some more details as just showing error is not enough. Definitely some part of code required to check exact issue.

Comment: Sir, which code I need to show here,

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by update compileSdkVersion from android-32 to android-34 and buildToolsVersion from 32.1.0-rc1 to 31.0.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).